# jQuery - popup inside popup

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, popup

[image]

So what i'm trying to acheive is, there'll be a large pop-up on click of a tile, and when you click on a tile inside that pop-up, another pop-up appears while simultaneously closing this one.

[image]

Now the problem is, if you see the second pop-up, the black overlay is a bit darker. The reason is, the overlay from the initial pop-up isn't going away. So when i close the second pop-up, the overlay still exists like below

[image]

I inspected the element, and found out that the overlay divs are getting stacked one below the other. So i tried to use the jQuery like this -

```
$(document).ready(function () {                                                                         
   $("#tilebtnonpop").click(function(){
      $('#epsimModalonpop').modal('show');
      $('#epsimModalLarge').css("display", "none");
      $('modal-backdrop:last-of-type').css("display", "none");                                                                         
   });
});
```

The modal-backdrop is the overlay div. When i use this script, the overlay completely goes off for the second popup. So the question is, how to make the overlay clear off.

Comment: Oops! I found the answer. I can simply use `$('#epsimModalLarge').modal('hide');`